# Configurar rota MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Dentro da pasta Controller do meu projeto MVC criei uma subpasta chamada cadastros,  que contem dentro 1 controlador chamado Cadastros (página inicial do módulo de cadastros) e os demais controladores de cada página.

Dentro da pasta view, tenho uma estrutura parecida, onde dentro da subpasta Cadastros tenho a view Index (para a pagina inicial) e as demais views do módulo.

No arquivo de configuração de rota, deixei da seguinte forma:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Cadastros",
            url: "Cadastros/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Cadastros", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "Aperam.PCP.PNB.UI.Controllers.Cadastros" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "Aperam.PCP.PNB.UI.Controllers" }
        );
```

Tenho outros controladores que estão fora da subpastas cadastro, como por exemplo ConsultaUM.

Ele funciona corretamente quando tento acessar os endereços:

- `localhost:63892/Cadastros`
- `localhost:63892/Cadastros/MotivoRealocacao`
- `localhost:63892/ConsultaUM`

Porem, quando realizo qualquer operação na tela de consulta UM, ele recarrega a página com o link `localhost:63892/Cadastros/ConsultaUM`.

No retorno da ação de pesquisa por exemplo, o retorno do controlador é

```
return View("Index", consultaUm);
```

Alguém sabe onde estou errando?

Comment: `ConsultaUM` está em qual *Controller*?

Comment: ConsultaUM é um controller que está na raiz da pasta Controller

Answer (score 0):

Possivelmente se *Controller* deve ter o *namespace* da primeira rota:

```
namespace Aperam.PCP.PNB.UI.Controllers.Cadastros 
{
    public class ConsultaUMController : Controller { ... }
}
```

Troque para:

```
namespace Aperam.PCP.PNB.UI.Controllers
{
    public class ConsultaUMController : Controller { ... }
}
```

Comment: Olá. Acabei de conferir e o namespace já está como seu segundo item.

Comment: Você tem certeza de que não existe outro *Controller* com este nome `ConsultaUM` dentro de `Cadastros`?

Comment: Conferi novamente e não tem outro controlador com este nome. Realmente não entendo porque depois da uma requisição é adicionado o "/Cadastros" na URL

Comment: Quando eu tiver um tempo, vou fazer um teste numa estrutura parecida, aí volto a responder.